# Error while displaying an image received from API response

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, axios

i'm trying to display a barcode received from the api request as an image. The api returns an object, so i turned it into json format to get the data attribute but i'm getting some unreadable characters as shown below, please how can i display this barcode as an image ?

image{"data":"�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000v\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005|��\u0000\u0000\u0001LIDATx^��1K�@\u0018\u0006�\u0004�8y�9\u001cfpp.:4\u0010.�б�{����X\b�A\u001c�:8\u0015\n�7��Y�����`0�\u001b\u001c\u001a̒@�y\u0011��M�8��\r��,���&����f0y��F\u001d��y�g��߳����X\u0010M�bŊ\u0015+V�X�b����r���\u0000��#\bR�\f�iĹ���\u001c�)�<\u0003��Ķ��]�/\u001eN�\u0016C��\u0014\u001a$v$[̢Sns��[4��ȣc��\t�D+���P�㳗�O��\nz\u0019\u0001�\u0015\u0019��\u0016�#W2�8[��\u00063\u0006�\t�x#�o1��ӄ���� %nc\u001b/\u0013�\u0017m��2C�vv%{\u0015\u0017��͵0{0IlWr�\u0003}�{��jk�\b�]I�@��X\b�,����\u0011�6�u$�EuvG�\u0010�9�s�3��!�\u0005\u00021��3�ͣ\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�","status":200,"statusText":"","headers":{"content-type":"image/png"},"config":{"url":"http://localhost:8084/codebar/00000000000000185882","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1},"request":{}}

this is my front end code:

```
    const [image, setimage]=useState([]);
    Service.getCodeBar('00000000000000'+tab[0].serial_begin).then(res=>{
    setImage(JSON.stringify(res))
    
}).catch(err=>alert(err));
console.log('image'+image)
return (
    <div>
        <PDFExport>
            <img style={{height:'30px', width:'45px', objectFit:'contain'}} src={AMPLITUDE} alt=""/>

            <img src={image} alt=""/>
        </PDFExport>
        <button style={{margin:'20px'}}className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>handleExport()}>Télécharger</button>
    </div>
)
```

}

and my back end code:

```
@Override
public BufferedImage generateEAN13BarcodeImage(String barcodeText) {
    EAN128Bean barcodeGenerator = new EAN128Bean();
    BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = 
      new BitmapCanvasProvider(160, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);

    barcodeGenerator.generateBarcode(canvas, barcodeText);
    return canvas.getBufferedImage();
}
```

controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/codebar/{codebar}", produces=MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> getEAN13Codebar(@PathVariable("codebar") String codebar) throws Exception{
    return okResponse(qDao.generateEAN13BarcodeImage(codebar));
    }

private ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> okResponse(BufferedImage image) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(image, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: try pointing image?.data to your <img src={image?.data} /> tag, or <img src={image?.url />

Comment: it works !! thank you for your fast response, i tried what u said it didn't work in the beginning but i changed  setImage(JSON.stringify(res)) to setImage(res.config.url) and it WORKS !!